# flask - path doesnt exist but same error still occur

Tags: python, flask

I get the following error when I run my app.py file

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2021 15:26:32] "GET /img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wP.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I made a complete new path that contains my PNG's and non of my files contains the keyword *wikipedia*. But I still get the same error, even though non of my files has nothing to do with that keyword. All my files are installed locally on my computer.

I tried rebooting my PC multiple times, create a new virtual enviroment for my app.py, install all dependicies again, and the error still keep occuring. Im using Visual Studio Code. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: May be its cache ? 
Did you tried in different browser ? or incognito  mode ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but using a different port did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe some other application is accessing the flask application. Try changing the port.

app.run(debug=True,port=5000)